# Perform nonnegative matrix factorization in R

Tags: r, matrix, sparse-matrix, matrix-factorization

I have a sparse matrix in R

I now wish to perform nonnegative matrix factorization on R

data.txt is a text file i created using python, it consists of 3 columns where first column specifies the row number, second the column number and third the value

data.txt

```
1 5 10
3 2 5
4 6 9
```

original data.txt contains 164009 rows which is data for 250000x250000 sparse matrix

I used NMF library and I am doing

```
x=scan('data.txt',what=list(integer(),integer(),numeric()))
library('Matrix')
R=sparseMatrix(i=x[[1]],j=x[[2]],x=x[[3]]) 
res<-nmf(R,3)
```

It is giving me an error:

> Error in function (classes, fdef, mtable): unable to find an inherited
> method for function nmf, for signature  "dgCMAtrix", "missing",
> "missing"

Could anyone help me figure out what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Give code to build an example sparse matrix, and (working) code to run your example.  Do you really mean -> there, or should that be <- ?

Comment: You're still missing a piece.  I don't have data.txt.  It's best to post R code that creates 'x', but posting example data itself is almost as easy to use.  (I can't say about others, but I prefer to use example code without > prompt, so I can paste it right from the website into R.)

Comment: oh data.txt is a text file i created using python,
it consists of 3 columns where first column specifies the row number, second the column number and third the value.

Comment: the point is not that we don't know what structure `data.txt` would have, it's that providing a **reproducible** example lowers the barrier to providing questions enormously; rather than starting by constructing an example, would-be answerers can start right in on diagnosing/answering the question.  Meet them halfway: http://tinyurl.com/reproducible-000

Comment: I just started coding in R last night and I have a very large dataset for the sparseMatrix ... my dimensions for sparse matrix are 250000x250000 and I dont really know how to provide a reproducible ... but I would really really appreciate any help with this .. I am workin on this for 24 hrs straight and did not get any result on web

Answer (score 4):

The first problem is that you are providing a dgCMatrix to nmf.

```
> class(R)
[1] "dgCMatrix"
attr(,"package")
[1] "Matrix"
```

The help is here:

```
help(nmf)
```

See the Methods section.  It wants a real matrix.  Coercing with as.matrix is likely to not be of very much service to you, because of the number of entries.

Now, even with your example data, coercion to a matrix is insufficient as written:

```
> nmf(as.matrix(R))
Error: NMF::nmf : when argument 'rank' is not provided, argument 'seed' is required to inherit from class 'NMF'. See ?nmf.
```

Let's give it a rank:

```
> nmf(as.matrix(R),2)
Error in .local(x, rank, method, ...) : 
  Input matrix x contains at least one null row.
```

And indeed it does:

```
> R
4 x 6 sparse Matrix of class "dgCMatrix"

[1,] . . . . 10 .
[2,] . . . .  . .
[3,] . . 5 .  . .
[4,] . . . .  . 9
```

Comment: okay so what is the solution? are you saying that it is not possible?

Comment: Your original data, presented as a matrix, may indeed be what you want (but no rank was specified in the question).  Unfortunately, such a matrix won't likely fit in your memory.

Comment: okay so if your answer is not an answer can you please delete it so that others wont misunderstand this for an answer

Comment: You asked, "What am I doing wrong."  In order for someone to answer how to do it "right," you'll need to tell us what you're actually trying to do.

Comment: @MatthewLundberg: The problem is that your 'solution' does not work for a 250000x250000 sparse matrix. Coercing it to a dense matrix will let you run out of memory (unless you have 1 TB of RAM ... :-)

Comment: @f3lix This isn't a "solution."  This is an answer to the question, "What am I doing wrong?"

Comment: @MatthewLundberg: ok, I see your point. user1344389 question is not so clear. He should have asked: how can I perform nmf on a 25K*25K sparse matrix in R?

Answer (score 1):

Almost 10 years later there are solutions. Here's a fast one.

If you have a `dgCMatrix` with 250k-square dgCMatrix that is anywhere near 1% sparse, you need a sparse factorization algorithm.

I wrote `RcppML::NMF` for large sparse matrices:

```
library(RcppML)
A <- rsparsematrix(1000, 10000, 0.01)
model <- RcppML::nmf(A, k = 10)
str(model)
```

That should take a few seconds on a laptop.

You might also check out `rsparse::WRMF`, although it isn't as fast.

Answer (score 1):

There is now an excellent NMF package available:
https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/NMF/NMF.pdf

Provides various heatmaps, purity/entropy, a selection of different NMF algorithms (Brunet, Lee, sNMF, nsNMF, euclidean/K-L divergence, etc.) and a framework to create your own.

Try:

```
library(NMF)
x = read.table('data.txt')
# estimate rank
estim.x = nmf(x, 2:5, nrun=50, method = 'nsNMF', seed = 'random', .options = "v")
# plot clustering accuracy
plot(estim.x, what = c("cophenetic", "dispersion"))
# inspect consensus matrices
consensusmap(estim.x)
```